# Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob when doing Here quick start guide

Tags: here-api

I am just starting out in Here API stuff, so if I have missed something, my bad.

I am following the [Here Quick Start Guide for the JS API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html).

I am working with RoR on my localhost.

My application layout:

```
!!! 5
%html{:lang => 'en'}
    %head
        %title= pgt
        %meta{:name => 'viewport', :content => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}
        %meta{:charset => 'utf-8'}
        = csrf_meta_tags
        = favicon_link_tag 'temp-favicon.png', :id => '_favicon_'
        = stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all')
        = stylesheet_link_tag('mapping/application', :media => 'all')
        %link{:href => '//js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :type => 'text/css'}
        = javascript_include_tag('jquery/application.js')
        = javascript_include_tag('first/application')
        %script{:src => '//js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8'}
        %script{:src => '//js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8'}
        %script{:src => '//js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8'}
        %script{:src => '//js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8'}
    %body
        = render 'layouts/partials/msg'
        = render 'layouts/partials/main'
        .md-overlay
        = javascript_include_tag('application')
```

_main:

```html
<div id="container" style="z-index: 98;">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

map page:

```
#primary_map
```

the js that runs on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': KEY
    });
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('primary_map'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom  : 12,
            center: {lng: 39.314079, lat: -84.431173}
        }
    );
    //var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
});
```

I keep getting the js error in the console: `mapsjs-core.js:376 Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:http://localhost:3000/876d80b9-e385-40b8-9e03-959a788b2ff4: e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function TypeError: e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

Console screenshots:

[console error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgu0F.png)

[console error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8IVw.png)

Not sure what is causing this issue and hoping that I can find some help. Thanks!

Comment: Any news? Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I just started using the HereMaps API. And my first step was trying out the sample code on my localhost from their Quick Start, and I'm getting the same issue. Maybe I also missed something in the quick start guide (although I did register, create api keys and added my domains to their whitelist)...... another issue I faced was that the API was giving me 401 (Unauthorized) error which I quickly solved by removing the "Referer" header after testing some API requests in Postman.

Comment: @KlaussU I was unable to find a solution for this issue. Since this was needed quickly, I moved to Bing Maps, which uses a lot of HERE's data and api I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I recently restarted working with HereMaps. So here is the thing. In one project we are kind of stuck for now with a pretty old version of Magento and all its glorious frontend. So here is what I did:

1. I debugged the code and found that this error was thrown because
   in HereMaps there was a for loop in which hasOwnProperty was not
   used and there were some unexpected properties leaking through the
   prototype chain;
2. I did a quick fix and added the hasOwnProperty check but as
   expected it still didn’t work and just silently crashed at some
   point without any errors, leaving me with a blank map. Then again I
   added a few breakpoints in their code and noticed HereMaps was
   trying to deal with an object coming from the PrototypeJS library
   that Magento has included;
3. At this point, I just decided to **isolate HereMaps JS and add
   their Quick Start code in an iframe** and of course, the “Tangram”
   error went away.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hello @KlaussU, I am having the same issue but on Emberjs framwork. If I understand you used the here maps on an iframe on your app. is this right ?

Comment: @BOUHOUALID Yes. Putting HereMaps stuff in an iframe (thus isolating it from other parts of the app) solved the issue.

Comment: I think it's related to the Tangram Engine which cannot load a yaml file discribing the scenes.. Thank you for your answer :)