# here basemap not loading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have built a PowerBI custom visual displaying a here map with markers and lines on it. In Chrome and Edge it works fine, but in Firefox the basemap is not loading.
When using the default basemap I get following errors in the console:

```
Tangram [error]: tile load error for tile with key 0/4/3/3/3 and id 32: undefined...
```

When I use the terrain basemap, I get following errors in the console:

```
Tangram [error]: Error for style group 'non-collision' for tile....
```

I have found these stackoverflow posts:

[HERE maps JS API 3.1 - Error for style group 'non-collision' in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218854/here-maps-js-api-3-1-error-for-style-group-non-collision-in-angular)

[HERE Javascript API - Map layer doesn't load properly on Safari and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931531/here-javascript-api-map-layer-doesnt-load-properly-on-safari-and-ios)

In both posts they point to the direction that the javascript is not loaded yet when the map is initialized.

I load the script by adding the script elemts dynamically to the dom- and wait until the script is loaded. First I load mapsjs-core.js, and when this is loaded I load mapsjs-service.js, mapsjs-mapevents.js, mapsjs-ui.js and mapsjs-ui.css in parallel. When all are loaded I create the here map. I have also tried to wait for 10 seconds after all are loaded before I create the map, but I get the same errors. In the network pane, I can't see any issues.

does anybody have an idea whats going on?
thanks for your help!

---

I have tried now the approach here-developer-support mentioned and have added an iframe in my powerbi visual with just this simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
        type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
        type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
  <script>
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    "apikey": "<my_key>"
  });
  var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();
  var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById("mapContainer"),
    maptypes.vector.normal.map,
  {
  zoom: 10,
  center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
  });
  </script>
```

Now, I get the same error also in Chrome:

```
mapsjs-core.js:425 Tangram [error]: tile load error for tile with key 0/10/275/168/9 and id 40: undefined
An @ mapsjs-core.js:425
(anonymous) @ mapsjs-core.js:425
```

Comment: Please try loading Heremaps in an iframe. Check this post for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087852/tangram-error-scene-load-failed-to-load-blob-when-doing-here-quick-start-gu

Comment: Custom Visuals in PowerBI are already in an iframe. and adding additional iframes in a custom visual is not allowed for security reasons as far as I have read. So thats not really an option. And why would such a name conflict only happen in Firefox, but not in other browsers? They are all loading the same javascript files.

Comment: I have updated my post above, I was not successful with the iframe approach. Any ideas what happens here?